# I created a html table by getting input from a json file . how to provide a function of filter search to it?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I created a html table by getting input from a json file . how to provide a function of filter search to it ?

I created an input field but i dont know how to process it further.

help me out with this work .

like when the user searches it should dynamically provide results.
if for example if i type "A" then it should show the results which has "A" in it. ?

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert JSON Data to HTML Table Example</title>
    <style>
        table, th, td 
        {
            margin:10px 0;
            border:solid 1px #333;
            padding:2px 4px;
            font:15px Verdana;
        }
        th {
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

    <div id="showData"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
  //  function CreateTableFromJSON() {
        var product = [
            {
                "S.NO": "1",
                "Brand": "Apple",
                "Model": "iphone5s",
                "Price": "60000"
            },
            {
                "S.NO": "2",
                "Brand": "Samsung",
                "Model": "galaxys8",
                "Price": "60000"
            },
            {
                "S.NO": "2",
                "Brand": "Apple",
                "Model": "iphone4s",
                "Price": "40000"
            },
            {
                "S.NO": "2",
                "Brand": "Redmi",
                "Model": "3sprime",
                "Price": "9000"
            },
            {
                "S.NO": "2",
                "Brand": "Redmi",
                "Model": "Note4",
                "Price": "14000"
            },
            {
                "S.NO": "2",
                "Brand": "Apple",
                "Model": "iphone3s",
                "Price": "30000"
            },
            {
                "S.NO": "2",
                "Brand": "Samsung",
                "Model": "galaxys7",
                "Price": "40000"
            },
            {
                "S.NO": "2",
                "Brand": "Redmi",
                "Model": "note3",
                "Price": "12000"
            },
            {
                "S.NO": "3",
                "Brand": "Apple",
                "Model": "iphone5",
                "Price": "45000"
            }
        ]

        // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
        // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
            for (var key in product[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }

        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = product[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);




   // }
</script>
 </html>
```

Comment: No need to re-invent the wheel. There are lots of available table scripts around you can use for this functionality

Answer (score 0):

You need to build `myFunction` to perform search action. I searched `Brand` and `Model`, you can add others if needed.

```
    function myFunction(){
      var table, input, filter;
      var searchResult = [];

      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      table.innerHTML = "";

      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

      for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        if (data[i].Brand.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          searchResult.push(data[i]);
        } else if (data[i].Model.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          searchResult.push(data[i]);
        }
      }

      fillTable(table, searchResult);

    }
```

Btw, I made a bit change for the first time loading the table.

```
// CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.id="myTable";

var data = [];
data = readJSON();
fillTable(table, data);
```

Also would suggest you split your script to funtions, so you can reuse them in search.

`function readJson`:

```
function readJSON() {
  var product = [{
      "S.NO": "1",
      "Brand": "Apple",
      "Model": "iphone5s",
      "Price": "60000"
    },
    {
      "S.NO": "2",
      "Brand": "Samsung",
      "Model": "galaxys8",
      "Price": "60000"
    },
    {
      "S.NO": "2",
      "Brand": "Apple",
      "Model": "iphone4s",
      "Price": "40000"
    },
    {
      "S.NO": "2",
      "Brand": "Redmi",
      "Model": "3sprime",
      "Price": "9000"
    },
    {
      "S.NO": "2",
      "Brand": "Redmi",
      "Model": "Note4",
      "Price": "14000"
    },
    {
      "S.NO": "2",
      "Brand": "Apple",
      "Model": "iphone3s",
      "Price": "30000"
    },
    {
      "S.NO": "2",
      "Brand": "Samsung",
      "Model": "galaxys7",
      "Price": "40000"
    },
    {
      "S.NO": "2",
      "Brand": "Redmi",
      "Model": "note3",
      "Price": "12000"
    },
    {
      "S.NO": "3",
      "Brand": "Apple",
      "Model": "iphone5",
      "Price": "45000"
    }
  ]

  // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER.
  // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')


  return product;
}
```

`function fillTable`:

```
    function fillTable(table, product){
      var col = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
        for (var key in product[i]) {
          if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            col.push(key);
          }
        }
      }
    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {

      tr = table.insertRow(-1);

      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        tabCell.innerHTML = product[i][col[j]];
      }
    }
```